# Apache Solr Client = How to enable "wire" logging (with log4j)

Tags: java, solr, log4j, slf4j, solrj

I would be very thankfull, if someone can tell me, how to enable "wire logging" (printing all the XML that is sent and received from the solr-java-client to/from the solr-server).

The Client i use: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJava
I use log4j!!

Both did NOT work in log4j config:

```
<logger name="org.apache.solr" additivity="false">     
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />  
  </logger>


<logger name="org.apache.commons.httpclient" additivity="false">     
    <level value="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />  
  </logger>
```

Solr internally uses another logging framework slf??? ,maybe this is the reason, but I do not know where to start here how to solve the problem.

Thanks!!!
Jens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr makes use of the [JDK Logging](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/) since [Version 1.4](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging).

Maybe this [tutorial](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/logging.jspx) will help you figure out how to configure your Tomcat for that.

Or replace the [slfj](http://www.slf4j.org/) api within the solr.war file with the one for log4j as mentioned in the Solr documentation.

If you want to have more information within the client look at the [SolrQuery](http://www.zihou.me/docs/solr/api/solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.html#setShowDebugInfo%28boolean%29) javadoc.

Hope this helps you a step forward.